# How to display a popup when a certain number is exceeded? (Vue.js & Boostrap)

Tags: vue.js

thank you for reading my question.

Now I have been trying to create EC site mockup by using Vue.js and Boostrap.

What I want to do is that
・show a message when the number of items selected is greater than the one in stock

[Here is the localhost page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSo1g.png)

↑please look right, I want to show the popup message like "no stocks" if the counter takes more than 8.

I am not usually using Vue.js and this is the first time. So I hope someone well-experienced about it would help me out.

```
<template>
<div class="category-page">
  <h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
  <b-row>
    <b-col cols="5">
    <input type="radio" id="one" value="one" v-model="picked">
    <label for="one">photo1</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="two" value="two" v-model="picked">
    <label for="two">photo2</label>
    <br>
    <span>Picked: {{ picked }} </span>
    <img :src="productImage" class="product-image" />


    </b-col>
    <b-col cols="7">
      <p>
        {{product.description}}
      </p>

      <p>
        Option selected: {{defaultOption.title}}
      </p>

      <p>
        Price: ${{defaultOption.price}}
      </p>

      <button v-on:click="counter += 1">+</button>
      {{counter}}
      <button v-on:click="counter -= 1">-</button>

    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'ProductPage',
  data: function() {
    return {
      picked: {},
      counter: 0,
      product: {},
      photo: {
        image: {
          one: require('./images/p1.png'),
          two: require('./images/p2.png'),
        },
      },
      defaultOption: {}
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://euas.person.ee/products/" + this.$route.params.productId)
      .then(response => {
        this.product = response.data;
        this.defaultOption = this.product.options[0];
      });
  },

  computed: {
    productImage() {
      return this.photo.image[this.picked];
    },
  },

}
</script>

<style scoped>
.product-image {
  width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Vue :)
You can achieve this by using `computed` property or call some function it `watcher`:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isShowNoStocksMessage"> No stocks </div>
</template>
...
  computed: {
    isShowNoStocksMessage() {
      return this.counter === 8;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    isShowNoStocksMessage: function(val) {
        if (val) { //call here logic to display popup }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just one line, use `v-if` :)

```
<div v-if="counter === 8"> No stocks </div>
```

if you have anything more complicated then follow @alex's answer.